# Interrupting an HTTP session with a forbidden error

Tags: netty

In my netty server application I receive an HttpRequest that must be processed only if a cookie with a particular content is present and is valid (a kind of authentication).
In my pipeline I have the following objects:

1. HttpRequestDecoder
2. MyCookieHandler
3. MyRequestHandler

What I want is that, if the cookie is not present or is not valid, no further elaboration occurs and a FORBIDDEN error is returned.

This is what I've done inside 'MyCookieHandler' :

```java
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
  ...
  if (!isValid(cookie)) {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(
      new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, FORBIDDEN))
      .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    return;
  }
}
```

However, as soon as the 'writeAndFlush' is called the client receives the error 'Empty reply from server'.

What's wrong in my code?

Thanks,
Massimiliano

Answer (score 1):

I found what was the error. Adding a future listener to the `ChannelFuture` returned by `writeAndFlush`, I discovered that the problem was that a `HttpResponseEncoder` was needed into the pipeline to encode the answer to a `ByteBuf`.

So, to solve the problem, I change the pipeline this way:

1. HttpRequestDecoder
2. HttpResponseEncoder
3. MyCookieHandler
4. MyRequestHandler

and now it works.